# If I have a vector of strings, how I can use the strings with execvp to execute a command?

Tags: c++, string, char, constants, execvp

I'm working on an assignment where I'm creating my own command shell. I have properly tokenized my input string into multiple strings. I'm trying to figure out how to use these strings with execvp.

The idea is that if I have a vector like this:

```
vector<string> s;
s[0] = "ls";
s[1] = "-a";
s[2] = "-l";
```

I want to be able to run the command `ls -a -l` using execvp.

I thought of using `c_str()` to convert my strings to `const char *`, because I thought that `execvp` takes in a `const char *`, but that didn't work for me.

How should I do it?

Thank you all for your help and feedback! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to `push_back` elements. Currently, the code has UB.

Comment: Why don't you just make a temporary `vector<const char *>` anyway?

Comment: @mnunberg Because that's minging?

Comment: Please don't forget that the array of string pointers passed to `execvp()` needs to have a `NULL` pointer entry at the end.  None of the examples so far show that important detail.

Comment: Also, if you're going to pass in an array of pointers to the strings in `s` (or whatever the source vector is named), for example by creating a `vector<char const*>` loaded with the `c_str()` values from `s`, then you need to make sure that the lifetime of `s` is at least as long as the `vector<char const*>` you pass to `execvp()`.

Answer (score 0):

using `execvp` you want an array of `char*` pointers as a second argument. I would go about it like this:

1. create your options
2. make a vector of pointers
3. directly use vector data

The code is:

```
char cmd[] = "ls";
char p1[] = "-l";
char p2[] = "-a";

vector<char*> parameters;

parameters.push_back(p1);
parameters.push_back(p2);


execvp(cmd, parameters.data());
```

You can only use `std::vector::data()` if c+11 compiler is available since `std::vector::data()` is c++11 feature. To use c+11 compiler, add `-std=c++11` to your compile options.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you don't have C++11, replace `parameters.data()` with `&parameters[0]` which works correctly in all versions

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

I created a function that takes a vector of `strings` as an input and outputs a vector of `char *`.

```
vector<char *> stringToChar(vector<string> s){
    vector<char *> c;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i){
        char *str;
        str = new char[s[i].size() + 1];
        memcpy(str, s[i].c_str(), s[i].size() + 1);

        c.push_back(str);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to make copies of the data... your new vector of `char*` can point at the existing strings.  Just pass `s` by reference and do `c.push_back(&s[i][0]);`